# cose-bilkent layout extension of cytoscpae.js

Tags: cytoscape.js, cytoscape, cytoscape-web

I have been using cytoscape.js library to develop an application, but the extension layout cose-bilkent is working fine in google chrome, but the same code gives an error in Internet Explorer.

I am getting SCRIPT5009: 'Set' is undefined error in th IE debugger. Please advise what I might be missing.

[Image with error in cose-bilkent.js file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z36lF.png)

Comment: Hi, could you please add the section in your code, which is causing this problem?     Thanks :)         Judging by the browser you want to use, the mistake is probably not on your side, IE isn't really supported by cytoscape.

Comment: Hi @Stephan T. , Thanks for the reply. PFA the screenshot of error in cose-bilkent.js file of cytoscape.js, a few layout extensions like Arbor is working fine in both IE and chrome. Also there is no error in my code.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common mistake (not yours, its the ie that is broken). IE doesn't support either Map or Set (expect for their "basic support"). You can see that [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Set#Browser_compatibility).

```
import 'core-js/es6/map';
import 'core-js/es6/set';
```

If you want to use it, there may be some workarounds with requireJS or polyfill, but using edge or ANY other browser than good ol' IE would do the trick...

Comment: Thanks Stephen. Could you please shed some light on how to use the extensions? I am using Maven framework and I am a bot confused about the registering concept of extensions. The index.js of all the layouts consists of the following code -

Comment: const impl = require('./layout');

// registers the extension on a cytoscape lib ref
let register = function( cytoscape ){
  if( !cytoscape ){ return; } // can't register if cytoscape unspecified

  cytoscape( 'layout', 'dagre', impl ); // register with cytoscape.js
};

if( typeof cytoscape !== 'undefined' ){ // expose to global cytoscape (i.e. window.cytoscape)
  register( cytoscape );
}

module.exports = register;

Comment: If you take a look at the [documentation](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/tree/master/documentation/demos/cose-bilkent-layout) provided by cytoscape, you see how to initialize cytoscape.

Comment: I saw the documentation, could please advise the correct way of using an extension like popper in Cytoscape. Downloading an including popper.js and cytoscape-popper.js in the script tag of index.html doesn't work.